# Auth0: getAccessTokenSilently after login returns token on desktop browser but fails on mobile browser

Tags: auth0

I am accessing the application on the same server in incognito tab in Chrome.
After login, getAccessTokenSilently returns a token on the desktop browser but not on a mobile it fails with "Error: Login required"

```
 await getAccessTokenSilently({cacheMode: 'on', timeoutInSeconds: 10}).then((token) => {
    alert('Got auth token');
    ...
 }).catch((e) => {
    alert(`No auth token found: ${e}`)
 });
```

Note: this seems to work after replacing loginWithRedirect -> loginWithPopup. Why would that make difference?

Comment: What browser is giving you the Login Required error? Are you using refresh tokens?

Comment: Chrome both desktop and mobile. No refresh tokens. Here's the site - loginWithPopup on mobile,  loginWithRedirect  on desktop. https://vocabuddy.net/

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to use popup on mobile, but redirect on desktop...

If you'd have a reproduction, I am happy to look into it for you. If you believe there is an issue with our SDK, feel free to reach out to us through GitHub.

I can't load your site as its marked as being malicious and blocked from accessing, so would need another way to reproduce it and assist.

Comment: It is not what I want, it is what I see working. Redirect does not work on mobile. I don't like popup on desktop. What do you mean "marked as malicious"? Provide a link, please. There's certainly nothing malicious, the site gets clicks from Google Ads. A link will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't link something, it's my machine saying it is and blocking access.

Anyway, I'm the one maintaining the SDK you are using, and loginWithRedirect should work fine on mobile, but there could be some factors in play, such as Safari that needs some more specific configuration.

If you think there is an issue with the SDK, you can open an issue on GitHub and I am happy to look into it, but I can not look at your website so will need something else to be able to reproduce if needed.